# k8s create service with port, targetPort and nodePort identical

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I need to create Kubernetes services that their nodePort are auto-allocated by K8S, and port/targetPort must equal to nodePort. (The requirement comes from the spec of a spark YARN node as the backend of the services).
Maybe I can first create the service with a fixed dummy port/targetPort and an auto-allocated nodePort, then update the service to set port/targetPort to the same value as the nodePort.
But is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main ways to expose a resource on k8s

First one using `kubectl expose` command: using this one you can choose the pod/deploy to expose but not the nodePort value. Then as you already know you must set the nodeport value on the created yaml

Another way to expose is using `kubectl create service nodeport` command: using this one you can set the port, target port and nodeport.

If you know the label of the pod to expose (for example `app: superPod` ) you can create a file, then replace a label (for example `TOREPLACE`)
with the value of your choosen port (for example 30456):

On linux:

```bash
portValue=30456 && k create service nodeport TOREPLACE \
--node-port=$portValue --tcp=$portValue --dry-run=client -oyaml > file.yaml \
&& sed -i 's/app: TOREPLACE/app: yourselector/g' file.yaml \
&& sed -i 's/name: TOREPLACE/name: yourselector-name/g' file.yaml
```

This will creates the file with preferred values.

After that, you can apply the file using `kubectl -f file.yaml apply`

However, depending on your needs, and if you want a reliable customizations of your resources, you could try to use:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/
or
https://helm.sh/docs/

Hope it helps.